# Import RDF/XML data into local DBpedia set up

Tags: rdf, dbpedia, virtuoso, rdf-xml

I have set up a DBpedia 3.9 mirror with Virtuoso 7.2.1 in my local PC. Now I have some data in RDF/XML format and want to import it into the local Virtuoso, so that I can run SPARQL queries on them.

Can anyone help me to do it?

Is RDF/XML format right enough to do that or any other format needed for it?

Answer (score 1):

First thing, updating to the current [Virtuoso 7.2.4](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews) is strongly advised, whether you're running [Open Source](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSDownload) or [Commercial](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/download/).

Now, to the data load -- RDF/XML is fine.  We recommend using the [Bulk Load tools](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader) in most such cases.

(ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).  We generally recommend bringing Virtuoso-specific questions to Virtuoso-focused areas, such as the [Virtuoso Users Mailing List](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/), [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or [OpenLink Support Cases](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).)